# CONTAINS predicate in queries to SharePoint CMIS connector

Tags: sharepoint, cmis

We have a problem with doing CMIS queries to SharePoint 2010.

**CONTAINS** predicate works in **WHERE** clause only in case when connecting through native APIs. It fails to work through CMIS connector, with following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: plain/text; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 9dc88273-bb44-463d-95fc-f87193e3398f
Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={f52ddea3-0d94-48e6-b7c0-53ae740be8e4}; path=/
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029
Date: Mon, 06 Aug 2012 12:17:34 GMT
Content-Length: 129

Your search cannot be completed because this site is not assigned to an indexer. Contact your administrator for more information.
```

SharePoint version details:

MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (not Foundation)

Answer (score 1):

Go to SharePoint Central Administration -- Application Management - Manage content databases and click the content database your web application is using. On the page that loads the database (Manage Content Database settings), scroll down to Search server section and select your server from the drop down. Check to make sure Preferred server for timer jobs also has your server selected. Click Ok. If the drop down is disabled, ensure SharePoint Foundation Search Service (yes, Foundation although you are running SharePoint Server) is started. Hope this helps.

http://www.sathishtk.com/blog

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone now. But new problem is that queries with CONTAINS return empty results, do you know what may be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did your SharePoint Foundation Search timer job work. Validate it by going to 
Monitoring –>Timer Jobs –>Review job definitions.

Look for - SharePoint Foundation Search Refresh and run the timer job. Once it is done, try your contains statements.

If it still does not work, what I would suggest is stop your SharePoint foundation search. Remove your web application (the one that has your document library) from the content sources (Search service application). Start your foundation search again, set the content database settings as stated in my previous post, start the foundation timer job and test your query again.

If it works, you can then add your web application to your content source so the regular SP search is working.

http://www.sathishtk.com/blog

P.S. I was trying to locate a technet blog that I used as a reference. Can't locate it. But if I remember right, these were the steps I followed.